# How do I update multiple inputs with the same name in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is what I have so far

Controller

```
       $i = 0;
     foreach ($this->input->post('skill') as $cat) {
     $data[$i++]['skill'] = $cat;
     }
     $this->db->update_batch('skills', $data); 
    }
```

Model

```
function update_record($data) 
{

    $this->db->update('skills', $data); 
   }
```

View

```
          <?php foreach ($skills as $skill):?>

<input type="text" name="skill[]" value="<?php echo $skill->skill;?>">

                <?php endforeach?>
```

I am getting a database error

```
You must specify an index to match on for batch updates.
```

Please help me fix this I tried googling and nothing is coming up.

Comment: have you tried using [where_in()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select) ?

Comment: You are calling update_batch fucntion from inside your controller and I cant see that method in your model

Comment: I am new to this and I am winging it sorry. Do you mean I need to put the update_batch in the model? @UmairIqbal

Comment: @ZathrusWriter I am trying to update the input I am not sure if that will do but i'll try.   edit: tried it and getting 

"Message: Array to string conversion"

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is the issue.
According to the [CI Docs for update_batch](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) you need to add a third parameter that is the where key . Here is an example from the docs.

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'My date 2'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'Another date 2'
   )
);

$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'title');
```

So, above in the queries the title column is what the row is compared to. So for the rows that have title as 'My Title' The first array element is used as update and for those with 'Another Title' the second element. I hope you understand. If we don't have a compare field then the whole database will be updated :-P

Here is the final query produced from the above operation.

```
 UPDATE `mytable` SET `name` = CASE
 WHEN `title` = 'My title' THEN 'My Name 2'
 WHEN `title` = 'Another title' THEN 'Another Name 2'
 ELSE `name` END,
 `date` = CASE
 WHEN `title` = 'My title' THEN 'My date 2'
 WHEN `title` = 'Another title' THEN 'Another date 2'
 ELSE `date` END
 WHERE `title` IN ('My title','Another title')
```

Hope this helps.